# Is it possible to load Bootstrap Glyphicons svg file into Inkscape?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, svg, glyphicons, inkscape

I want to be able to display a Glyphicon Halfling with a border of about 13% all around the icon, and had thought of doing this by modifying the SVG file using Inkscape. However, when I open the SVG file in Inkscape, although I don't get an error the page appears to be blank (for example, I can't select anything). This seems a bit weird to me - but maybe I am going about this the wrong way entirely?

Answer (score 2):

"glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg" is not your standard SVG file. It is an SVG font.  This answer on the superuser site may be of help:

https://superuser.com/questions/309743/edit-svg-font-using-inkscape

Comment: Many thanks. I think what I wanted to do was a bit atypical - it was to be able to use glyphicons as images in Axure and have them display properly including on workstations that don't have the glyphicons ttf installed. However, I have since discovered that in Axure I can convert characters to images, so that problem is

Comment: Many thanks. I think what I wanted to do was a bit atypical - it was to be able to use glyphicons as images in Axure and have them display properly including on workstations that don't have the glyphicons ttf installed. Consequently, I wanted to convert the svg font to svg image. However, I have since discovered that in Axure I can convert characters to images, so that problem is sorted. This [Helpful sheep post](http://helpfulsheep.com/2015-03-25-converting-svg-fonts-to-svg/) might be useful to anybody trying to sort out the problem. (hit the wrong button and saved the post by mistake)